What predicate expression should I use in the "if" function to ask if the button was pressed?
Here is the event handler:
$levelUp.addEventListener('click', () => {   
      $circle.setAttribute('src', './assets/lizzard.png'); // меняем картинку 
},)

When I click on it, the picture changes. Here is the required function that should say that if the button was pressed then...:
function (???????????) {
     $levelUp.innerHTML = " ";
}

What should I write instead of question marks?
I've tried assigning the event handler to true in different places.
$levelUp.addEventListener('click', () => {
---> buttonClicked = true <-----
    $circle.setAttribute('src', './assets/lizzard.png'); // меняем картинку
},);

$levelUp.addEventListener('click', () => {
    $circle.setAttribute('src', './assets/lizzard.png'); // меняем картинку  
}, --> true <--);

but most likely I'm doing something wrong.

This is a pretty classic XY problem. What are you trying to achieve by doing this (thinking in big-picture terms)? It's possible there's a better way to achieve what you want that doesn't involve your current solution.

the main thing is to assimilate the information. the whole purpose of this site is to find problems through lack of experience and observation

What should I write instead of question marks? whatever you like. The name of function arguments contains no special meaning. Call the argument something that conveys its meaning to you. How are you calling that function?

let buttonClicked = false;

// Event handler to set the flag when the button is clicked
$levelUp.addEventListener('click', () => {   
    buttonClicked = true;
    $circle.setAttribute('src', './assets/lizzard.png'); // Change the image
});

// Function that checks if the button was pressed
function checkButtonClick() {
    if (buttonClicked) {
        $levelUp.innerHTML = " ";
    }
}

